# 1 GHz RF bandpass filter

Tags: rf

Is it possible to design a good bandpass filter with center around 1GHz, using capacitors and inductors?

Or does these components perform too poorly at these frequencies?

I would rater not try to design my filter as a cavity filter (soldering pipes and all).

Comment: For low powers you could use a microstrip or SAW filter.

Comment: How narrow does the filter need to be, i.e. what should the Q be, ideally ?

Comment: It needs to be really narrow, but I found a lot of suitable saw-filters. So I think maybe two saw-filters will do the job.

Comment: No, you wouldn't normally use lumped LC components for this unless your requirements were very loose.  How many of these filters do you actually need?  If this is a one-off project that doesn't need to be very reproducible, just search eBay for "ghz filter" and you'll see some ready-made options that may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 1 GHz filter can be built using lumped elements and might be suitable for your purposes, but a better filter could be built using microstrip or a cavity. It depends on your requirements. The filter type depends on the performance you require; for instance, a Butterworth filter is optimal in terms of pass-band ripple.

I use this software for LC filter design: http://tonnesoftware.com/elsie.html. It's excellent.

I'd prototype the filter on a piece of PCB material, and test and adjust it using a suitable signal generator and RF meter. If it's a one-off, you can simply mount it in a screened enclosure with the input and output connectors.